# failed installing PyAudio on Windows 8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio, failed-installation, python-3.9

This is what i am facing while installing PyAudio and i have also installed visual c++ to resolve this issue but no success

```
C:\Users\prasun\Desktop>pip install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Building wheel for pyaudio (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\python 39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\prasun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-85mknslj\\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\prasun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-85mknslj\\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\prasun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ozoj8htv'
       cwd: C:\Users\prasun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-85mknslj\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\
  Complete output (17 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\python 39\include -Ic:\python 39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
  _portaudiomodule.c
  c:\python 39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
  src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
  src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python 39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\prasun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-85mknslj\\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\prasun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-85mknslj\\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\prasun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ippb99hf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python 39\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\prasun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-85mknslj\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\
    Complete output (17 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DMS_WIN64=1 -Ic:\python 39\include -Ic:\python 39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    c:\python 39\include\pyconfig.h(117): warning C4005: 'MS_WIN64': macro redefinition
    src/_portaudiomodule.c: note: see previous definition of 'MS_WIN64'
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29333\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python 39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\prasun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-85mknslj\\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\prasun\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-85mknslj\\pyaudio_6bba70697ef146e492839ed6f9b4633b\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\prasun\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ippb99hf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python 39\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

please do help me with this as it's my first project with python.

waiting for your response
thanking you in anticipation

Comment: PyAudio-0.2.11 was released in 2017, and you're installing it on Python 3.9 - one of the latest Python versions. Its internals might have changed enough to break a 3 yr old package

Comment: thank you will try installing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The error MSVC is complaining about is all about the sources of PortAudio that you need to have available in the directories MSVC is looking for to find sources.

You will probably need to download the [sources of PortAudio](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/) to have `portaudio.h` header file.

Some documentation on [building on Windows](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs-dev/compile_windows.html) that you might find useful too.